# Invalid JSON character when running ng serve

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

I am getting following error when running ng serve...

```
PS F:\Projects\RecipeApp> ng serve
Invalid JSON character: "\"" at 76:13.
Error: Invalid JSON character: "\"" at 76:13.
    at _token (F:\Projects\RecipeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\json\parser.js:63:19)
    at _readArray (F:\Projects\RecipeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\json\parser.js:316:9)
    at _readValue (F:\Projects\RecipeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\json\parser.js:561:22)
    at _readProperty (F:\Projects\RecipeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\json\parser.js:398:19)
    at _readObject (F:\Projects\RecipeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\json\parser.js:431:30)
    at _readValue (F:\Projects\RecipeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\json\parser.js:564:22)
    at _readProperty (F:\Projects\RecipeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\json\parser.js:398:19)
    at _readObject (F:\Projects\RecipeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\json\parser.js:431:30)
    at _readValue (F:\Projects\RecipeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\json\parser.js:564:22)
    at _readProperty (F:\Projects\RecipeApp\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\json\parser.js:398:19)
```

I am using angular version 6

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace?

Comment: Remove node_module folder , run npm install again.

Comment: please post your error as text, not as an image.

Comment: I experienced the same problem. It happened after git merge which makes conflict. Just check your angular.json file.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Check your Angular.json.

It seems that this config file is not correct.

---

Update for clarification:
A misplaced "/" in the `angular.json` will create exactly that kind of error.

Comment: You'r Answer could be comment.

Comment: In this case it´s the answer, because you will get exactly the described error, if you put a "/"  at the wrong place in your Angular.json.
But, yes, you are right, this could also be a comment to clarify the error description.

Comment: There was syntax error in my angular.json. I'd added a line to the 'styles' section, but forgot to add a "," on the end of the previous line.

Comment: In my case, a comma was missing from the end of a line in angular.json.

Answer (score 9):

In my case the problem was Visual Studio 2017 adding [UTF-8 BOM characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom/38038099#38038099) to **angular.json** after I edited the file.

Permanent solution for Visual Studio and Angular CLI was to open the file once and save as **UTF-8 without signature**

1. Go to `File` -> `Save As`.

[image: FileSaveAs]

2. Then on Save button click on triangle and click `Save with Encoding...`.

[image: SaveAsPopUp]

3. From Encodings dropdown select `UTF-8 Without signature` -> Click `OK`.

[image: AdvancedSaveOptions]

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me since am using  Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 2):

Open the file in Notepad++ and change the encoding to UTF-8 then save
it will work for sure :)

Comment: Its mainly due to the syntax error in angular.json file. make sure there is a comma (,) in every end of the previous line. and also check the slash ( / and \ ) in path. use "/" instead of "\".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've added a path in the angular.json file with "\" instead of "/".

Answer (score 0):

Its mainly due to the syntax error in angular.json file. make sure there is a comma (,) in every end of the previous line. and also check the slash ( / and \ ) in path. use "/" instead of "\".

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue as described while using the "ng g c" command. The issue was that I forgot a comma (,) while adding a second style-sheet to the angular.json file.

Hope this helps someone,
Vlad

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the missing **comma(,)** end of the line at 76 raw in the `angular.jason` file. just put the comma `"your_jason_code",` and go to the next line.

sample:

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css", 
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

if you miss the comma end of the line, you will get that error.

Answer (score -2):

Make sure **angular.json** encoding in `UTF-8` not `UTF-8-BOM`.