# ng command returns "Unknown Error : Error : Invalid JSON character: "a" at 0:0"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

Installed Node JS version 12.19.0 for my Windows 10 64 bit machine and the npm default version was 6.14.8

Installed angular cli using the command `npm install -g @angular/cli`

When i try any ng command from the command prompt it returns the error message

> Unknown Error : Error : Invalid JSON character: "a" at 0:0

i followed the solution in the link [Invalid JSON character when running ng serve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51517046/invalid-json-character-when-running-ng-serve) and converted the angular.json file encoding to UTF-8 using Notepad++ and having the path of ng in the environment variables i.e., C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin

I have an angular.json file in my users folder and it starts with `angular.json` text. I know the issue is in that file , but i don't know how to fix it.

I have the npm and nodejs path variables in place. Nothing seems to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two angular.json because when the project has it own angular.json
Change the name of it or delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the `angular.json` in my users/ folder and that did the trick for me. As Abedin.Zhuniqi suggested, i think you cannot have more than one `angular.json` files in your system

Comment: Nope as the official documentation from Angular tells us.
`The application builder uses the webpack build tool, with default configuration options specified in the workspace configuration file (angular.json) or with a named alternative configuration`.